# 試験期間は今日を含めて約2週間後の月末 meaning

Tags: meaning

> **試験期間は今日を含めて約2週間後の月末。**

**期間**: period; term; interval.

**含めて**  ---> **含める**: 1. to include (in a group or scope)​, 2. to instruct; to make one understand​, 3. to include (a nuance); to put in (an implication)​, 4. to put in (someone's) mouth​, 5. to permeate with flavor.

In my interpretation, that sentence means that the exams/tests will be held in about 2 weeks later (in 2 more weeks), at the end of the month. There's 2 parts that I don't quite understand, **期間** and **含めて** in that sentence. The exams/tests will be held an completed in a day, so I wonder what the meaning of **期間** in that sentence. **今日を含めて** literally translated as 'including today', is it 'start from today' or 'after today' the 2 weeks period will be counted from?

Thank you in advance for your kind guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sentence seems puzzling to me, too. The literal translation is "The exam period is at the end of the month, which is about two weeks later including today." This の is an apposition marker (cf. 3日の月曜日 "Monday, the 3rd").

今日を含めて is "including today", but it is technically unnecessary (2週間後 is "14 days later", which is not ambiguous), and it does not go well with 約 ("about", "roughly"). 試験期間 indeed means there are multiple days. If the exam is held only for one day, 試験は(約)2週間後の月末(だ) should have been enough.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I read the next sentences mentioned the exam (written tests) will be over in one day (all 5 subjects), and the school gives 2 weeks period for the students' preparation. 期間 makes it sounded like the exam is 2 weeks long. I'm just thinking that perhaps 今日を含めて (including today) means that in the next 2 weeks from today. Is it a proper interpretation?

Comment: @AmandaZhang That reminded me, in some schools, the phrase 試験期間 may also include the preparation periods (2 weeks in your case). In this period, club activities may be restricted, for example. Still, if the author had used 試験期間 in this sense, the sentence should've been "試験期間はこれから約2週間、月末までだ" or something similar.

Comment: It was a sentence from a light novel. I'm learning Japanese language while reading it. I think I get the meaning through your explanation with 試験期間はこれから約2週間、月末までだ.

Comment: @AmandaZhang Yes, maybe the author failed to include まで.